# How to find out file downloading time in php?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, post, header

On click of download excel button in my application,i am creating a excel file using PHP EXCEL library.The downloading time is more if data is around like 10,000 rows from database. On click of download I need to display like **Please wait x seconds or minutes to download file** .My application is in PHP and I am not storing file in my directory.

My code is Like This

```
$sqlFields = "SELECT * from table_name ORDER BY name";//it gives 10,000 rows
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/lib/PHPExcel.php");
$objPHPExcel    = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel_11 = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

foreach ($sqlFields AS $List) {   
    //here putting data to excel cells
}

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');  
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Report '.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'.xls"');  
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');   
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');  
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: $sqlFields = "SELECT * from table_name ORDER BY name";//it gives 10,000 rows

 include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/lib/PHPExcel.php");
 $objPHPExcel    = new PHPExcel();
 $objPHPExcel_11 = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

foreach ($sqlFields AS $List) {   
    //here putting data to excel cells

}

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Report '.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'.xls"');
 header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); 
   $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
 $objWriter->save('php://output');

Comment: Downloads can get an automatic progress if you specific a `Content-Size`. If you want a progress bar for the excel file generation part, that's a bit trickier. You could poll with XMLHTTPRequest or push with Server Sent Events. Whether this usefull depends on where the bottleneck is, is it generating the file or downloading the file?

Comment: Plese check my question I have updated my question with code.

Comment: On click of download button, first I am generating the file then downloading